# htaccess rewrite (old domain to new domain both www and non-www)

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I am attempting to do redirect an old domain (regardless of whether it has a www prefix) to a new domain without the www.  e.g.:

olddomain.com > newdomain.com

www.olddomain.com > newdomain.com

I've got it so that the redirects from non-www are working, but the if www is used, the domain does not redirect.

This is on a Wordpress site, so I'm including the bits that Wordpress uses, too.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# ### Begin custom domain redirect ###
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.olddomain.com\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://newdomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://newdomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
# ### End custom domain redirect, back to the standard WP stuff ###

RewriteRule ^/index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Comment: I know this is old but I wanted to point out that your www olddomain wouldn't work if you had .com twice: `^www\.olddomain.com\.com`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)olddomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

which will handle incoming URLs with and without the www.

And move the `RewriteBase /` to above the WP block; it may be causing a problem being in the wrong place.

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Comment: If you make `www.` optional with `?` like `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?olddomain.com [NC]` you can use one `RewriteRule` for both www and just the domain name using the `%1` back reference - `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]`

Comment: Except that it looks like both should go to the new domain without www, so you just need to add `?` to make `www.` optional.